# Regex to include all characters with at least one letter and at least 6 characters long in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

**What i have did so far?**

I have created this regex

`/[.*a-z][*\w*\W]{5,}/i`

Which should do the following:

1. `[.*a-z]` : search for at least one letter.
2. `*\w` : search for zero or more word character (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore).
3. `*\W` : search for zero or more non word character (+-= etc).
4. `{5, }`: search if there is at least 5 characters of `[*\w*\W]` and the `[.*a-z]` looks for at least one character which as combined is a total of 6 characters.
5. `/i` : search for lower and well as upper case.

**What is the problem?**

I expect the above regex to accept a string that include at least one letter anywhere in the string but it only works if the letter is included at the beginning. why ?  for example: the string `y12345` works but the string `123y45` doesn't. As my regex does not include a caret (`^`) but it seems to act like there is a caret (`^`) present at the start of my original regex. like so `/^[.*a-z][*\w*\W]{5,}/i`

And i would also like to know if that is the perfect regex for a password ?

Thanks for your time much appreciated.

Comment: Try this `/[a-zA-Z]/g.test(str) && str.length > 6` where `str` is the name of your string.

Comment: I did this `/[.*a-z][*\w*\W]{5,}/ig` but that still does not work.

Comment: Your regex won't work for `78s234`

Comment: One thing I *always* recommend for troubleshooting regex expressions is to google "online regex tester JavaScript" (or whatever language you're working in. Use said tools to test your expressions before coding them out.  Many often have features and resources to help you code it properly as well.

Comment: @SherylHohman That is the tool i always use for my regex testing.I am using https://regex101.com/r/Tl2sVZ/1/

Comment: @SherylHohman I am using it take a look https://regex101.com/r/Tl2sVZ/1/

Comment: "Perfect" regex for a password, should be a separate question.  Or rather a separate google search.  Also, the answer depends on your password Requirements (ie what restrictions do you tell the user that they must fulfill).  I certainly say that a password length of `6` is *not* a perfect requirement for a password, nor, by extension, the perfect regex.

Comment: It concerns me that 6 characters is all you're requiring for a password.

Comment: @SherylHohman I was planing to change it to 8.

Comment: @SherylHohman After reading this post: https://blog.codinghorror.com/password-rules-are-bullshit/ I came to a conclusion that you should not enforce any rule to your password (except the minimum number of characters) and you should include Unicode in your password. So with that in mind i edited my regex to this:  `/.{8,}/u`.What are your thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this;

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{6,}$
```

You can find the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/HXXk8Y/1).

The pattern matches with these words;

```
y12345
123y45
yyyyyy
12345y
```

Comment: I don't understand how it matches for non word characters can you please explain ? you have not used `\W` or specified any special character but it still matches for non word character how ? Is it because of `.` in `.{6, }` ?

Comment: Using the '\W' is not must. The pattern simply looks for positive lookahead match any character ".*"(Word or nonword) but at least should be one word character. ([a-zA-Z])

Comment: After reading this post: https://blog.codinghorror.com/password-rules-are-bullshit/ I came to a conclusion that you should not enforce any rule to your password (except the minimum number of characters) and you should include Unicode in your password. So with that in mind i edited my regex to this: `/.{8,}/u`.What are your thoughts ?

Comment: There are many approaches to enforce password policy. In my opinion, the password must contain upper-lower case words, numeric and special characters and character length should be at least minimum 8. With your regex pattern, for example the client can set the password as "11111111". And actually, it comes me to simple and wrong.

Comment: As I said, this is my opinion. The decision is yours.